# offsetHeight is zero when using document.write to create a document

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm writing a unit test to test an Angular 5 directive that uses document.querySelectorAll to select some elements.  I create the below mock service that returns the div elements that meet the `selector` criteria.

```
class MockDocumentService {
  querySelectorAll(selector: string) {
    const doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('');
    doc.open();
    doc.write(`<html><body><div>
    <div MaxHeight="testMaxHeight">some text</div>
    <div style="height:100px" MaxHeight="testMaxHeight">a taller div</div>
    <div MaxHeight="testMaxHeight">some text</div>
    </div></body></html>`);
    doc.close();
    return doc.querySelectorAll(selector);
  }
}
```

It successfully returns the elements however in my directive is have the following:

```
const elements = documentService.querySelectorAll(selector);
let maxHeight = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  maxHeight = (<HTMLElement>elements[i]).offsetHeight > maxHeight ? (<HTMLElement>elements[i]).offsetHeight : maxHeight;
}
```

Finally, the problem, the offsetHeight is always zero (note that one of the div elements has a style attribute setting the height to 100px).  How do I get the offsetHeight to be reported correctly.  Another note, the directive code works fine in actual use.

Answer (score 0):

The `offsetHeight` will return zero when the element isn't rendered in the DOM.

> Typically, an element's `offsetHeight` is a measurement in pixels of the element's CSS height, including border, padding and the element's horizontal scrollbar (**if present, if rendered**). It does not include the height of pseudo-elements such as :before or :after.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

You could try something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  document.body.appendChild(elements[i]);
  maxHeight = elements[i].offsetHeight > maxHeight ? elements[i].offsetHeight : maxHeight;
  document.body.removeChild(elements[i]);
}
```